# Can't figure out UnboundLocalError in Python

Tags: python

The code block, embedded in a function:

```
try:
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(log))
except OSError:
    pass
```

The error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'OSError' referenced before assignment
```

What could this possibly be a symptom of?

Comment: OSError should be imported by default.  Which Python version is this?  If you ran ```from exceptions import OSError```, would it run properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an unfortunate source of confusion in the Python 2 exception-catching syntax. Somewhere in the function, you did something like the following:

```
except SomeError, OSError:
```

That looks like it's catching two exception types, but it's not. `OSError` is actually interpreted as the name of the variable you want to hold the `SomeError` instance you're catching. That means when you try to catch `OSError`:

```
except OSError:
```

`OSError` refers to the local variable you didn't realize you created.

To catch multiple exception types, you need to parenthesize the list of types to catch:

```
except (SomeError, OSError):
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code assigns to `OSError` somewhere in the function, which means that the compiler has marked it as a local variable. Verify every bit of code where that name shows up to verify that you aren't using it incorrectly.

Comment: Is this the only possibility? Because I scoured my code, and it doesn't do that.

Comment: @verve: I bet you did something like `except SomeError, OSError:`. You need to parenthesize the errors, like `except (SomeError, OSError):`, or Python will think `OSError` is the name of the variable you want to use to hold the `SomeError` instance. This is one of the reasons the `as` syntax was introduced.

Comment: On second thought, this ^ is very likely.

Comment: user2357112, you're right. Make your comment an answer, and I'll accept it.